# My program to verify Armstrong numbers fails for number 153

Tags: c, numbers

I did a program to verify the [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number). The program successfully verifies the Armstrong numbers except 153. Can anyone help me out?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,m,i,r,s=0,temp,c,count=0;
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    temp = n;
    m = n;
    while(m>0)
    {
        r = m%10;
        count++;
        m/=10;
    }

    while(n>0)
    {
        r = n%10;
        s = s + pow(r,count);
        n = n/10;
    }

    if(s == temp)
    {
        printf("%d is a Armstrong num",temp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a Armstrong num",temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: On another couple of notes: You don't need that `<conio.h>` include, and shouldtry to avoid its use. It's non-standard and therefore non-portable. And in most cases (like here) not even needed. Also please for future questions only tag the language you're actually program in, don't tag multiple languages. Lastly, for integers try to avoid the floating point `pow` function. Create your own function which uses a loop to do the multiplication using integer arithmetic.

Comment: Don't use `pow()`. `pow()` brings in floating-point innacuracies... `pow(10, 2)` may equal `99.9999999999976567542367239`. Write your own integer version (possibly with `long long unsigned` results).

Comment: how do i convert pow( ) value from double to int when it returns double value can u plz help me out

Answer (score 3):

Using `pow` (and more generally float numbers) in integer calculations is ***ALWAYS*** a very bad idea.

Your code with one small change:

```
int intpow(int r, int c)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(c--)
    {
        result *= r;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and instead of

```
s = s + pow(r,count);
```

lets use our new function:

```
s = s + intpow(r,count);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dreeKvre9

Result (ta-dam!! - magic):

```
153 is a Armstrong  num
```